# Add dynamic fields by pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code add a new text field when I press the ENTER screen on the keyboard but it only works on the first text field on the next when I just typed the value and pressing Entrer it does not add a new field.
Already leaves a search in the questions of forum and not find the solution.

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    </div>


    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $('input, text').on('keypress', function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".add_field_button").click();

            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine

Comment: @SujitAgarwal the problem starts when I click on the second text field type and press enter

Comment: Check @abderrahim's answer. That would fix your issue.

Comment: What you need is "event delegation" - you should read about it as it's a common issue when creating interactive elements dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code :

```
 $('body').on('keypress','input[type=text]', function(e){
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".add_field_button").click();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes it's a common error in Jquery with dynamically added element you have to bind them to an existing element like body in this case

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi Your answer worked perfectly and just takes me another question, I need it to go into the new text field type a TAB. It's possible?

Comment: Also if you don't want to bind it to the whole `body`, you could bind the event handle to your `<div class="input_fields_wrap">` since that is there from the start. `$('.input_fields_wrap').on...` instead of `$('body').on...`

Comment: @IncredibleHat sure

Comment: I was just mentioning it as an alternative for @IsrayaneNayara :) Your answer works, and `body` is fine.

Comment: @IsrayaneNayara move to next input it's default Tab button behavior but you can override it and set the focus into the next() input to this

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi I'll give it a look. Thanks.

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi I tried $ (this) .prev ('input'). focus (); and it did not work. And $(this).prevAll('input:first').focus()

Comment: please make a working exemple here jsfiddle.net and i will take a look after

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP AND YOUR TIME. SOLUTION: $ ("input").focus ();